# Field values and Labels not saved when using Spring-Neo4J

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I'm using spring-data-neo4j to save some java objects to a neo4j db through the rest api.
The non-index fields of the objects don't seem to have been saved when observed from the db. Also the type specified by the @TypeAlias annotation is also not getting saved.
Any ideas on why this may be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I had used Neo4jTemplate.createUniqueNode(Object o) instead of Neo4jTemplate.save(Entity e)